# blender 3.4 when combining textured objects only the last one still has the right texture

Tags: texturing

[image]I have textures on all of the logs but when I join them to make one object to make it easier to move the textures screw up except the last one selec[image]ted

Comment: hm, seems to be something with the UV's. Do you use a uv map or generate it? Maybe the objects have different scales and rotation, when joining them the final object has the transforms of the last selected object and could destroy a procedural uv map.
Could you provide your Material Nodes?

Comment: I am very new here .how do I post what you asked for? I have the photo of the material nodes but I don't know how to post it.

Comment: Click on edit (on the bottom of the question). then drag oder copy paste the image

Comment: other than baking your setup to UV, you could use e.g. geometry nodes, to assign locations of your objects to attributes, then your shader could read this attribute data to offset the object location. The thing is, though, if you want to export this object to some game engine, you still will need to bake the textures, whereas if you need it for rendering, then why even join the objects?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to UV unwrap the objects before joining, as your shader is set up at this moment it will try to sample the entire object as 1 instead of multiple smaller parts.

To UV unwrap it you'll want to select the mesh in Edit mode then hit 'U', you can unwrap in many different ways, to get the best results I would suggest creating the UV layout yourself using the normal Unwrap function after applying seams. If you don't know how to apply the seams you'll just have to select the edges that you would like to mark as a seam and right click -> mark seams. You can select the following edges like in this picture:

[image]

Then your UV map should look something like this:

[image]

Select the islands and scale and move till you're satisfied with the pattern!

If you are duplicating the same object to create that bundle, UV ing 1 stick then duplciating it, the UV map should hold all the same. After you'll be able to join without losing the texture mapping you have!

Always UV yourself when possible :) The Mapping node doesn't always know what to do in these situations!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try to unwrap it